# Discrete mathematics - Reflexive, Symmetric, Anti Reflexive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Question, I know there are formulas for Reflexive relations, which is the $2^{n^2-n}$.
And for Symmetric: $2^\frac{n^2+n}{n}$
I saw a video of Anti Reflexive, and there was the same calculation when A was: $A={(1,2,3,4)}$
They calculated the Anti reflexive, and it was the same as the reflexive relation.
I mean, the number of relations of Anti-Reflexive was $2^{12}$ Which is the same as Reflexive relations $2^{12}$.

**Could I say the number of Anti-Reflexive relations and number of Reflexive relations are the same? ( Basically the question for summarize )**

Comment: What have you tried? Btw, the number of reflexive relation on $\{1,\dots,n\}$ is $2^{n^2-n}$ (not $2^{n^2-2}$).

Comment: Oh sorry my  bad, yea its n, not 2, I will fix it in a minute.
What do you mean what I have tried?

Comment: @drhab Alright, fixed it :) sorry, again.
About trying, I saw it on a video to be honest, but even so, If I try it myself, I get the same thing.

Comment: You get the same thing ... for $n=4$. What do you get for $n=3$? for $n=5$? See also the questions listed under Related on this page.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yea I know, but I wanted to make sure. 
So number of anti-reflexive and anti-reflexive are the same right? I always make sure with people because I don't want to make a silly mistake because of it...
And one more same thing ( which I really didn't find online ), does there exist a relation of symmetric or relation transition? a formula I mean? like with Reflexive and Symmetric?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Also, my English is not that good to be honest, and all I see are some questions regarding writing the relations, instead of calculating it.

Comment: All these questions have been asked and answered on this site before. Please do a little searching, so we don't clog the place with duplicates. [There was a "how many anti-symmetric relations?" question under related a few minutes ago, but it's gone now. Still, it's on the site somewhere....]

Comment: I cant find it on the relations... maybe I dont know what to write exactly, as I said, my english is not at its best, If I could show you what I have in the post at related, I dont have any reason to lie... All I see are proofs of stuff, not the number.
You can choose not to believe me, but I dont have any reason to lie, as if I could find it easily, I would not have opened the post, believe me, it would have taken 1min to find the answer and then thats it. ( instead of me going to google translate, latex guide and such to write this post for like 15min )

Comment: @drhab Yea, Thanks :)
I really didnt know how to write my exact question exactly, that question the person wrote, I have no idea how I should have wrote that same thing... ( with set A of size n and such ). but never mind, I got my answer:) thanks